# Extract (total) file size for multimedia files in Tridion?

Tags: 2009

I wonder if I can actually somehow easily extract the actual volume in SDL 2009 CMS for images and videos that has been uploaded by the editors?

I have looked at the tridion_cm database and I could "count" the items by an innerjoin on ITEM_MMT_ASSOCIATIONS to MULTIMEDIA_TYPES.

Select count () as.. on this and I get

- 17   video/mp4
- 10   video/quicktime
- 542 image/png
- 3 application/x-msaccess
- 15 application/ms-powerpoint
- 24664 application/pdf

and so forth. But I wonder if anyone know a nice way to actually get the "volume" in size as well?

How much video or pdf are stored in the CMS?

I know that in FILE_EXTENSIONS I can get  MULTIMEDIA_TYPE_ID = 16 for mp4 files. I can also run a query like
SELECT sum(binary_size)
  FROM [Tridion_cm.[dbo].[ITEMS]
  where FILE_NAME like '%.jpg'
and check "file_name"..

Are there any other nifty ways?

Comment: If they're all published... you could look at the sizes on the published side? Otherwise, time to brush up on VBScript (or .NET with COM interops) and write some recursive logic to open up each multimedia component and add up the bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example of how to retrieve image properties from an MMComponent using TOM.NET:

```cs
                            Image tridionImage;
                            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                mmComponent.BinaryContent.WriteToStream(stream);
                                tridionImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
                                height = tridionImage.Height.ToString();
                                width = tridionImage.Width.ToString();
                                String size = tridionImage.Size.ToString();
                            }
```

This can be adopted to be used in a Custom Page for SDL Tridion 2009 and the Core Service in Later versions as well.
The Core Service API has the following Property for file size: `BinaryContentData.Size`.